# SQL Command to assign average value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to find out how to do this in sql. Using SQL Server Management Studio
I have a big table with data such as

```
Store           Month              Value
------         --------           -------
  A              JAN               1000
  A              FEB               2400
  A              MAR               2310
  A              APR               1409
  A              MAY               1500
  A              JUN               1000
  A              JUL               2400
  A              AUG               2310
  A              SEP               1409
  A              OCT               1500
  A              NOV               1409
  A              DEC               1500
```

I have the above data but i want to have the average value of the month by dates. for example

```
Store           Month              Value
------         --------           -------
  A           1/1/2014             32.25
  A           2/1/2014             32.25
  A           3/1/2014             32.25
  A           4/1/2014             32.25
  .              .                   .
  .              .                   .
  .              .                   .
  .              .                   .
  A           31/1/2014             32.25
```

where the value of 32.25 is derived from dividing the total number of days in JAN(31) with the value of 1000...

1000/31  = 32.25

And i got to do this for the rest of the months.

Anyone got any idea on how do i do it? I am totally stucked. I tried using excel to do it manually but there are too much data and different stores

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18626/how-to-get-the-total-days-per-month-between-two-dates these answers may contain the information you require to proceed.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? if 2012 - use Value / EOMONTH('2014-' + Month + '-01')

Comment: Eh i am using SQL server 2014 express version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to find the number of days in the month and use that to divide up the value per day. If you don't want the actual range of dates, but just month + avg. per day, then the first queries should work, the full date range is included in the last query.

Please note that I used 2014 as year, so if you want to run the query for a leap year you have to adjust accordingly.

For SQL Server 2012+: (using the new eomonth function)

```
select 
    store, month, value, 
    cast(value as decimal(10,2)) / datepart(day,eomonth(cast('2014-' + month + '-01' as date))) as val_per_day
from table1
```

For SQL Server < 2012: (using date functions)

```
select 
    store, month, value,
    cast(value as decimal(10,2))/datepart(day,
    cast(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, cast('2014-' + month + '-01' as date))+1, 0)-1 as date)) as val_per_day
from table1
```

If you want the days too you can use a common table expression to generate a table with all days in the year and use that for a left join:

```
;With cte(d) as
(
    select cast('2014-01-01' as date) as d
        union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, d)
        from cte
        where d < '2014-12-31'
)

select *,
    cast(Value as decimal(10,2))/ 
    -- for pre 2012
    datepart(day,cast(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, cast('2014-' + month + '-01' as date))+1, 0)-1 as date)) as val_per_day
    --day(EOMONTH(d))  -- for 2012
from cte c
left join table1 t on t.month = left(datename(month, d),3)
option (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81f544/2) showing the results.